# Does Laravel Framework instantiate every model class at boot?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

`With`, `where`, `hasMany` etc. methods of Eloquent class are not static.

However we call these functions like that:

```
// Post is a child of Model class.
Post::where(...); // we don't use New keyword.
```

So, does Laravel Framework initiate all Model instances before we call their methods?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Eloquent's Model class, you have the below function which handles the static method calls dynamically.

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    return (new static)->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

As you can see, it creates an instance of the Model class on which a non static method is invoked statically, then invokes that method on the instance.

Comment: Is the instance destroyed following to method execution?

Comment: The usual function variable scope is applicable here as well. Once the logic inside the function is complete and returns the result, the instance will be destroyed.